# WPF Performance Suite Visual Profiler does not work

Tags: wpf, profiling

I have installed the latest Windows 7 SDK which contains the WPF Performance Profiler.

Perforator does display some data when I launch my app, but the Visual Profiler does not display anything. The timeline moves but not data is collected ...

Answer (score 17):

Try this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jgoldb/timezone-patch-to-wpf-performance-profiling-tools-for-wpf-4-is-now-available)

> In the [WPFPerf Performance Profiling Tools for WPF 4 is now available!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jgoldb/wpfperf-performance-profiling-tools-for-wpf-4-is-now-available) post, I mentioned that a bug caused the Visual Profiler to not display any data in certain time zones.
> A patch is now [available](https://web.archive.org/web/20060719041159/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en) to fix this issue...

Comment: The second time I tried to install and patch, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

First check to see if its working even with a small blank WPF application. If it is not working with a blank WPF app, then it likely is the patch already mentioned ([TimeZone patch to WPF Performance Profiling Tools for WPF 4 is now available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/08/24/timezone-patch-to-wpf-performance-profiling-tools-for-wpf-4-is-now-available.aspx)).

However, in my case that wasn't the issue. Visual Profiler has a bug that causes it not to display the Element tree if it doesn't like some of the characters in its main window title bar.

Through hours of trial and error, I was able to trace the root cause of why it would not work on our application even though it would on a blank WPF application. The reason is that our application has a special character in the title bar text (trademark). If we eliminate the special character from the main window title, the element tree shows fine when the visual profiler is attached. I was able to reproduce this issue in the simple blank WPF application too simply by putting the following property on the main window:

```
<Window ..... Title="Test Application™" >
```

Looks like a bug in Visual Profiler that somehow is triggered by special characters. I didn't test for other special characters, but likely it isn't just this one.

So the workaround is to remove the special character while you are profiling until they fix this.

Comment: It's 2019, and bug still exist. Thanks to you, I managed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out if you are using the version 4.0 of WpfPerf. The original that comes with the SDK do not support .net 4